# psutil and du give different output

Tags: psutil, du

I'm checking the directory size, but `du` and `psutil` gives so much different outputs,

```py
>>> import psutil
>>> print(psutil.disk_usage("/home/user1"))
diskusage(total=52586614784, used=3006468096, free=49580146688, percent=5.7)
```

so the used size is 3006468096 bytes, (roughly 2.9 GB)
.

With `du`,

```
du -sb /home/user1
498960095   /home/user1
```

, which is roughly 0.5 GB.

For me the du result seems correct (as there aren't many things in the directory), but I wonder why psutil gives such result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that psutils is giving you the total size of the mounted block disk where the directory you're passing exists (e.g.: `/` possibly). You can confirm with checking `df -h` output.